# Gridview onclick each view

Tags: gridview, onclick

I split my page four with gridview and I want to click each view like button and each of them goes another activity. But I dont know how can I set my java. is it same like button?  but it doesnt accept: could anyone help me set java. thanks

```
 <GridLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:columnCount="2"
    android:rowCount="2">

    <View
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:id="@+id/a"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:layout_rowWeight="1"
        android:background="@drawable/rectangle"/>

    <View
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:id="@+id/b"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:layout_rowWeight="1"
        android:background="@drawable/rectangle"/>
```

and java gives error:

```
public class ferr extends AppCompatActivity {
Button a, b, c, d;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.ferr);
    a = (Button) findViewById(R.id.a);
}
```

}